# Inverting the scaling of LSTM forecasts (tanh activation function)

Tags: r, lstm, forecasting

I am working in R and the monthly time series of the M3 competition data (with values mostly around the 1000s).

I want to scale the series from -1 to 1 in order to satisfy the tanh activation function of LSTM. Then I want to invert scale the forecasts back, but I cannot wrap my head around this.

I have tried including the min and max of the time series using rescale() from library(scales), but the inverted forecasts are way too big (around +-10,000s to 100,000s).

It’s the opposite when I don’t include the min and max, which are way too small (under +-100s).

Any help getting my head around this is greatly appreciated. I am only trying to replicate Jason Brownlee’s “How to Tune LSTM Hyperparameters with Keras for Time Series Forecasting” but his work was in Python.